# How do I link from one Azure AD custom page to another

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a link on my website that takes a user to the Azure AD edit profile page. I have customized that page by adding 2 links at the bottom. One is for the user to change their password and the other is to update a phone number. These are 3 different policies within Azure AD. When I initially link to the page from my site I am sending a clientID and a redirect_uri in the query string. Unfortunately this is getting converted to a csrf_token and those query string parameters are gone so I don't have access to them to include them in the change password and change phone number links. When the user clicks on the links obviously they fail. How do I link someone from one custom policy page to another page in Azure Active Directory? My custom page uses javascript, css, and html. No server side code other than what Microsoft injects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a link back to your application, and your application should understand that this route starts a new authentication journey with the appropriate authentication library with the desired policyId for this URL path. Do not link B2C journeys directly from within your custom HTML, you go via your application.

Comment: Thanks I created a landing page with my links.